# Using the tornado RequestHandler is it possible to get POST data without specifying a argument?

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to get the POST data from this CURL statement:

```
curl -d 'DATA HERE' http://localhost:8888/
```

I cannot find a method to do this, at the moment I am using an argument in the POST request:

```
curl -d 'data=test' http://localhost:8888/
```

and this to retrieve the data:

```
postData = self.get_argument('data', 'No data')
```

That works fine but I do not want to have to specify a POST argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The raw body from a post request is in `self.request.body`